# Blinking/Flashing without fade

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have problems to flash a border on/off/on/off... without fading. It should be 2s on and 2s off.

That's what I have:

```
<BeginStoryboard>
   <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
      <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
         <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0.1" />
         <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1" />
      </DoubleAnimation>
   </Storyboard>
</BeginStoryboard>
```

Comment: Does your code even compile? With `DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame` as a child of `DoubleAnimation`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<BeginStoryboard>
    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0" />
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1" />
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="0" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</BeginStoryboard>
```

Comment: Thank you. That's it!